# LongListSelector empty style

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I want to show a `TextBlock` when the LongListSelector has no items. I can do it to every list in my app but that is not sane. So I am trying to edit the list style and do it to every list.

How can I bind to the LongListSelector ItemsSouce count inside its style?

Here is where I am now.

```
<Style TargetType="phone:LongListSelector">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:LongListSelector">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ScrollStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.5" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Scrolling">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NotScrolling" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <!-- HERE I CANT BIND TO COUNT -->
                            <ec:DataTrigger Binding="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}" Comparison="Equal" Value="0">
                                <ec:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=EmptyListText}" PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </ec:DataTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <ViewportControl x:Name="ViewportControl" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalScrollBar" Opacity="0" Background="{StaticResource ThemeBackground}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Vertical" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="EmptyListText" Visibility="Collapsed" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Literals}, Path=Literals.noResults}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a DataBinding issue.

Try attaching it to the TemplateParent (which is the LongListSelector) like so:

```XAML
<ec:DataTrigger
    Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplateParent}, Path=ItemsSource.Count}"
    Comparison="Equal" Value="0">
</ec:DataTrigger>
```

That should set you straight if you want to use your triggers.

---

I like using `Converters`.  It is a little simpler to understand so here's the full solution using a Converter.

```C#
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Data;

public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        else
        {
            if (value is System.Collections.IList)
            {
                System.Collections.IList list = (System.Collections.IList)value;
                if (list.Count == 0)
                    return Visibility.Collapsed;
                else
                    return Visibility.Visible;

            }
            else
                return Visibility.Collapsed;                
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So the LongListSelector Style is:

```XAML
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! but in your first example there is a `Binding` word missing. should be: Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplateParent}, Path=ItemsSource.Count}"

Comment: @MarcelodeAguiar haven't used behaviors/triggers in awhile, thanks for comments.  I will change it.  Glad it worked for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom composite control based on the long list selector which does what is required and has the smarts to show a specific message per a dependency property.